# Prove that $M_{p}$ is an ideal of the p-integers

Tags: number-theory

I need to prove that:

$M_{p}:=\{ x \in \mathbb{Q}:|x|_{p}<1\}=\{ \frac{a}{b} \in \mathbb{Q}:b\in \mathbb{Z}-p\mathbb{Z},a \in p\mathbb{Z} \}$

Is an ideal of the p-integers and p-integers/ $M_{p}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ (integers modulo p).

The asociativity is clear since if we have $x,y,z \in M_{p}$, they belong to $\mathbb{Q}$, that is a field, now the identity element $0 \in M_{p}$ because by definition $|0|_{p}=0<1$, now since $\mathbb{Z}-p\mathbb{Z}$, $p\mathbb{Z}$ are clearly rings, we have that the inverse exists and belongs to $M_{p}$. My question is How can I show that $aM_{p}$ for all $a$ in the p-integers we have $M_{p} \subseteq aM_{p}$?, and how can I construct the isomorphism to $\mathbb{F}_{p}$? Thank you :).

Comment: How is $\mathbb{Z}-p\mathbb{Z}$ a ring? $2+3\not\in \mathbb{Z}-5\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Then am I right in the other things I wrote? And I don understand your above comment. Is the map you are refering to is the identity? Thank you @ Prometheus

Comment: You haven't shown that inverses exist in $M_p$. In fact inverses don't exist in $M_p$. I'm not sure what you meant by that sentence. Also neither $p\mathbb{Z}$ nor $\mathbb{Z}-p\mathbb{Z}$ are rings, so what you said definitely doesn't make sense.

Comment: Ok I have my doubts there :) how can I fix it ?

Comment: Ok themn my $M_{p}$ is your $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$

Answer (score 1):

As you say, associativity follows from $M_p$ being a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$.

To show $M_p$ is an ideal, you have to show that given $a/b$ and $a'/b' \in M_p$, then $a/b+a'/b' \in M_p$, and also given $a/b \in M_p$ and $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, then $na/b \in M_p$. For each of these you have to check that some $|\cdot|_p<1$. That will show it's an ideal.

Now I assume by $p$-integers you mean

$$\mathbb{Z}_{(p)} = \{ x\in \mathbb{Q}: |x|_p \leq 1\}.$$

One way to do the rest is this:

Consider the only possible map $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$, sending 1 to 1. Compose this map with the quotient $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}/M_p$ to get $f: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}/M_p$.

You want to show $f$ is surjective and has kernel exactly $p\mathbb{Z}$.

So let's consider the kernel of $f$. It's all integers $n$ that end up in $M_p$ once you send them to $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$, i.e. all the ones with $|n|_p < 1$. Why is that exactly $p\mathbb{Z}$?

Once you know the kernel is $p\mathbb{Z}$ you can factor $f$ through $\mathbb{F}_p$ and get a map

$$ \phi: \mathbb{F}_p \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}/M_p.$$

Next you need to show $f$, or equivalently $\phi$, is surjective. Suppose $a/b \in \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is some arbitrary element. We can assume $b$ is not divisible by $p$ (Why?) We already know $a$ is in the image of $f$, because it's just an integer, so if we could show $1/b$ is in the image of $f$ too, then we'd have $a/b$ is in there, and we'd be done.

So we actually want to show the multiplicative inverse of $b$ is in the image of $\phi: \mathbb{F}_p \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}/M_p$. Now use the general fact that a ring homomorphism sends mutiplicative inverses to multiplicative inverses.

Comment: Thank you @Prometheus, then the isomorphism is done the only thing that rest is proving this : show that given a/b and a′/b′∈Mp, then a/b+a′/b′∈Mp, and also given a/b∈Mp and n∈ℤ, then na/b∈Mp. For each of these you have to check that some |⋅|p<1. That will show it's an ideal. is it ?

Comment: I am sorry @Prometheus but I am having problems to prove that given a/b and a′/b′∈Mp, then a/b+a′/b′∈Mp, I know I have the triangle inequality in the p-adi norm but, in general if $|x|_{p}<1$ and $|y|_{p}<1$ does not imply that $(|x|_{p}+|y|_{p})<1$

Comment: You have to use the ultra-metric triangle inequality. $|x+y|_p \leq \max\{|x|_p,|y|_p\}$

Comment: Ok then we have that: $|x+y|_{p}<max\{|x|_{p},|y|_{p}\}<1$ isnt it :)

Comment: Yep, that's right.

Comment: Then then the isomorphism is done the only thing that rest is proving this :  given a/b∈Mp and n∈ℤ, then na/b∈Mp.  That will show it's an ideal. is it ? Is right isnt it :)

Comment: Ah, well, now that I look at it, you need to do it for $n\in \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$, but that shouldn't be harder.

Comment: WEll if I have problems I will tell you :) thank you :)